# Converting GPX track_points layer to CSV with lat/lng with ogr2ogr

Tags: convert, ogr2ogr, gpx

What's the correct command to convert a GPX track_points layer to CSV **with** lat/lng coordinates using ogr2ogr?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv input.gpx -lco GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ
```

with some warnings should do the trick. Warnings do not concern points geometry.
That command could probably be enhanced to remove *extra* warnings and handle only points. That would be your work ;-))

Edit : See the [dedicated page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_gpx.html) for enhancements. You will be able to query only *track_points* and cast timestamp using *-sql* options. By the way, even if you get a warning regarding timestamp, it will be written as plain text into your csv file.